# Why can we just replace $z$ by $ z^2$ in this Taylor expansion?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

When we expand $\sin(z^2)$, we can apparently just replace $z$ by $z^2$ in the Taylor series obtained by expanding $\sin(z)$. I can't see why. I mean, we can see that the derivatives of $\sin(z^2)$ will be a messy, with a lot of cos and sin, what make us conclude that just to replace $z²$ is enough to get the right series? The same thing goes to any Taylor series? I mean, if $f(x) = \sum x^n f^{(n)}(0)/n!$, when can we conclude that $f(x^2) = \sum x^{2n} f^{(n)}(0)/n!$?

Comment: Yes, the derivatives of $\sin(z^2)$ will be messy, but a lot of that messiness vanishes when you evaluate at $z=0$.

Comment: I've written a very detailed answer on this (albeit everything I wrote was for real numbers but the logic extends verbatim to the complex case; also I talk about some other stuff). See [Why can arbitrary functions be substituted into Taylor Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3707671/568204). Bottom line is the series for $\sin$ converges for all complex numbers. If $z$ is a complex number, then $z^2$ is also a complex number hence the series can be evaluated on this complex number.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang That's an important point that I think a lot of people missed in answering this - mind writing up an answer that shows it?

Answer (score 13):

This is a good question! The extra ingredient that we need is the theorem that *power series are unique*. More precisely: if there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-c)^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n (x-c)^n$ both converge and are equal for all $|x-c|<\delta$, then $a_n=b_n$ for all $n\ge0$. From this theorem, and the fact that the power series you constructed definitely equals $f(x^2)$ which also equals the Taylor series of $f(x^2)$, you can indirectly conclude that the Taylor series of $f(x^2)$ is actually given by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} f^{(n)}(0)/n!$.

Comment: What is the name of this uniqueness theorem?

Comment: The derivative of a function is unique, as well...

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion here stems from an abuse of notation.  In the case of differentiation, we are not merely making a substitution for the argument of a function - we are defining an entirely different function through function composition.  Strictly speaking, $\sin(z^2)$ has no derivative, because it is not a function - rather, it is a value in the codomain of $\sin$.

When we write $\frac{df(x^2)}{dx}$, we do *not* mean $\frac{df}{dx}(x^2)$.  The former can become quite messy; the latter is just a substitution, same as you've done with the power series.

A good way to avoid this type of confusion is to remember that differentiation acts on the *function*, not on its *argument* or on its *value*.  If you stick to explicitly defining your functions (e.g. avoid shortening $z \to \sin(z^2)$ to just $\sin(z^2)$), it should be much clearer what is actually going on.

Comment: What do you mean $\sin z^2$ has no derivative?   The derivative$\frac{d \sin z^2}{dz}$ exists, and also, if you mean $\frac{d \sin z^2}{d (z^2)}$, this exists.

Comment: I mean that a real number has no derivative.  Formally, $\sin(z^2)$ represents *the value of the codomain of $\sin$ to which $z^2$ is mapped*.  Using $\sin(z^2)$ to represent the function $z \to \sin(z^2)$ is an abuse of notation, with the consequence of the abuse being some nonintuitive rules around substitution.

Comment: Is not the derivative of $\sin z^2$ well defined, for example, by the chain rule?

Comment: No.  The derivative of $z \to \sin(z^2)$ is well-defined, and can be computed with the chain rule, but it formally makes no sense to speak of the derivative of just $\sin(z^2)$ - one might as well speak of the derivative of $4$ or $e$ or $-20$.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I must admit, don't really understand if what you are saying is a subtle point that I am missing, or if it is just semantics.  Hopefully there will be some further clarification.  If you don't like $\sin (z^2)$ then okay, $z\mapsto \sin (z^2)$ or $f(z)=\sin(z^2)$ should work.  Either way, $\frac{d(\sin z^2)}{dz}$ is what it is.

Comment: Yes, but notice that once we're explicit about functions being functions the confusion from the OP conveniently dissolves; we can see that in one case (differentiation) we have a dummy argument being used to define a function (which can then be shown to be equal to some other function, via the chain rule), and in another (the power series equivalence) we have two real-valued expressions of the same (not dummy) variable that are equivalent.

Comment: What @user3716267 is saying is that derivative of the *function* $f$ defined by $f(z) = \sin(z^2)$ exists, but for any *given* $z$, $\sin(z^2)$ is a number, not a function. eg $\sin(1^2)$, $\sin(\pi^2)$ etc are all constants.  It's a matter of notation and terminology.  In general $f(x)$ should not be considered a function, but rather, $f$ is the function and $f(x)$ is the output from $f$ for an input $x$.

Comment: I don't see how this resolves the issue, though.

Comment: The issue is that we have two ways of evaluating a power series for $g$ defined by $g(x) = f(x^2)$, one given by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n g^{n}(0)/n!$ (the Taylor series by definition), and the other by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} f^{n}(0)/n!$; and a priori it's not clear that these power series should be the same.  It implies an interesting fact, that $g^{2n}(0) = \frac{(2n)!}{n!} f^{n}(0)$. Greg has the right idea pointing to uniqueness of power series coefficients; how do you prove they are the same without uniqueness, or else some inductive argument?

Comment: My reading of the OP is not confusion that there are two equivalent expressions for the power series, but rather confusion as to why power series obtained by merely substituting $z^2$ in for $z$ is valid in the first place (and how this squares with such "substitutions" being invalid in the derivative calculations that are used to compute the power series).  Whether the series is unique is a more subtle concern (if we know the series converges to the value we want, we may not necessarily care about uniqueness).

Comment: @user3716267 I see, I interpreted the question differently.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to go back to Taylor polynomials to convince yourself. If a polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ satisfies
$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{f(z)-P(z)}{z^n} = 0,$$
then it must be the $n$th degree Taylor polynomial of $f$. Using this, you can easily prove that if $P$ is the $n$th degree Taylor polynomial of $\sin$, then $Q(z)=P(z^2)$ is the $(2n)$th degree Taylor polynomial of $\sin(z^2)$. The rest follows immediately.

Answer (score 2):

$f(\omega) = \sum \omega^n f^{(n)}(0)/n!$

Let $\omega=x$:  $f(x) = \sum x^n f^{(n)}(0)/n!$

Let $\omega=x^2$: $f(x^2) = \sum x^{2n} f^{(n)}(0)/n!$

Answer (score 2):

Missing ingredients

**Uniqueness of Taylor Series**

If a function $f$ has a power series at $a$ that converges to $f$ on some open interval containing $a$, then that power series is the Taylor series for $f$ at $a$.

**Uniqueness of Power Series**

Let

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x−a)^n$$

and

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}d_n(x−a)^n$$

be two convergent power series such that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c^n(x−a)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}d_n(x−a)^n$$

for all $x$ in an open interval containing $a$. Then $c_n=d_n$ for all $n \geq 0$.

Bringing you to

**Power replacement in Taylor series**

If the functions $f(x),f(x^k)$ have power series at $a$ that converge to $f(x),f(x^k)$ respectively on some open interval containing $a$, then the formal substitution $(x-a) \to (u-a)^k$ in the Taylor series for $f(x)$ brings the Taylor series of $g(u)=f(u^k)$ at $a$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ that converges to $f(x^k)$ on the same open interval containing $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with an easier example. Suppose that a function $g$ is given by the equation

$$g(x) = x + 6.$$

Can we conclude that

$$g(8) = 8 + 6?$$

Yes, absolutely. When we say that $g(x) = x + 6$, what we actually mean to say is that *for all real numbers $x$*, $g(x) = x + 6$. We're saying that this equation is true for every possible real number that $x$ could possibly be. And the number $8$ is a real number, so the equation is true when we put $8$ in for $x$.

The same goes for Taylor series. Suppose we know that for all $x$,

$$f(x) = \sum x^n \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}.$$

Can we conclude that

$$f(8) = \sum 8^n \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}?$$

Yes, absolutely. The number $8$ is a real number, so the equation is true when we put $8$ in for $x$.

We have other options, though. We don't have to use a literal number; we can put *anything* in there, as long as that thing we're putting in represents a real number.

So, if $y^2$ is a real number, can we conclude that

$$f(y^2) = \sum (y^2)^n \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}?$$

Yes, absolutely. The number $y^2$ is a real number, so the equation is true when we put $y^2$ in for $x$.

(Technically, this process is called *universal instantiation*.)